# Computation of iterated logarithm function

Tags: algorithms, iteration

I recently came across the iterated algorithm function denoted as $\lg^* n$.

But I am having a hard time understanding this statement:

$\lg^* n = \min \{i \ge 0: \lg^{(i)} n ≤ 1\}$

I could not understand what $\min$ set is used to signify. 
Also, could someone please provide an example of how this works.
I also came across examples like:

$\lg^* 4= 2$

But could not understand the computation, specifically how did they take up the values of i?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lg^* n$ is just the *minimum* number of times you need to apply the $\lg$ function to $n$ in order to obtain a number that is smaller than or equal to $1$.

For example, assuming that you are working with base-2 logarithms and that $n=65536$ you have the following:

- $\lg^{(0)} 65536  = 65536$,
- $\lg^{(1)} 65536  = \lg 65536  = 16$,
- $\lg^{(2)} 65536  = \lg 16  = 4$,
- $\lg^{(3)} 65536  = \lg 4  = 2$,
- $\lg^{(4)} 65536  = \lg 2  = 1$.

As you can see $4$ is the smallest integer value of $i \ge 0$ for which $\lg^{(i)} 65536 \le 1$. Therefore $\lg^* 65536 = 4$.

Comment: Okay. noted. But how could we get to define a recurrence based on it ? BTW, Thank you for the clear and concise explaination.

Comment: What do you mean by "define a recurrence based on it"? Do you want a recurrence relation that has $\Theta( \log^* n )$ as a solution?

Comment: Reurrence like stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm

Comment: So you want a recursive definition of $\log^* n$? There is one right in the page you linked.

Comment: Yeah. But how could we get to it.

Comment: Sorry. I fail to understand what you are asking. We are talking about a definition. It does not need be derived from anywhere. One can define whatever function he wants... Are you asking for an example where the $\lg^* n$ function naturally arises?

Comment: Okay I got it. Thank you.

Comment: Also I came across a solution which had: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+\lg^* n )}{\lg^* n}$ solved as : $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+n )}{n}$. I did not get how is $\lg^* n$ being replaced by n?. Link: https://walkccc.github.io/CLRS/Chap03/3.2/#32-4-star

Comment: It is just using the subsitutition $t= \lg^* n$. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+ \lg^* n)}{\lg^* n} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+t)}{t} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+n)}{n}  = 0$.

Comment: Cannot understand the last step how $t$ turned to $n$: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+n)}{n}  = 0$

Comment: I just renamed $t$. The name of the variable is meaningless.  $ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+t)}{t} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+n)}{n} = \lim_{q \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+q)}{q} = \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+z)}{z} = \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{\lg(1+y)}{y} = \dots$

Comment: Ohh okay okay I see. got it thank you.